# Is there a way to define the required sbt version in build.sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

In the build.sbt definition of a Scala project, is it possible to define the minimum version of sbt that is required to build the project?

Comment: you define the sbt version in build.properties. What do you mean by minimum version? Any version greater than the minimum version is fine?

Comment: @mohit Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`project/build.properties` allows you to force sbt to use particular version. If current version of installed sbt is different - sbt itself will download (if needed) the version you've specified there:

```
sbt.version=0.12.0
```

See, [Hello](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Getting-Started/Hello.html) for instance. So actually you may have installed several versions of sbt in your system - it's just jars, that placed in `.sbt/boot/scala-{scala.version required by this sbt}/org.scala-sbt/sbt/{sbt.version}` folder. Sbt executable actually looks for version specified in `project/build.properties` or (if it's not specified) highest version installed in the system.

P.S. From `sbt-launcher` perspective, sbt is only one dependency with small non-intersecting others like `ansi.jar`, so specifying the range of versions like `[0.13.1, 0.13.8]` have no much sense as it would be efective only for conflicting transitive deps. Otherwise it's enough to specify higher possible version (which would compile) - you may even choose some version that you already have (and update project's sbt that way).

Comment: OK so I can specify a particular version but not "greater-than", is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Greather-than has no sense here as you can automatically have any version of sbt on computer.  If you really need the greather-than + exception - you can check it manually inside `build.sbt` by analizing `sbtVersion.value`, but this isn't cannonical way for sbt.

Comment: Greater-than would actually be nice. If you're going to use syntax that was, say, introduced in 0.13.6, it would be nice to indicate that the minimum version needed is 0.13.6, but if you're using 0.13.7 that's fine (i.e., it's not necessary to download 0.13.6).

Comment: @Jun-Dai Bates-Kobashigawa It might not be fine actually if syntax changed again in 0.13.7

Comment: True, but in my limited experience they are generally backwards compatible—i.e., 0.13.7 will likely work with files built against 0.13.6, but any file built with new features in 0.13.7 will never work in 0.13.6.

Comment: @Jun-Dai Bates-Kobashigawa might be, eitherway another sbt version it's just one simple dependency, it's relatively cheap to download it (especially if you have several other dpendencies in your project). For very rare offline case - nothing stops you from specifying 0.13.7 directly - it's like "I agree with backward-compatibility risk" and it's a good for project itself as it means that version of sbt was updated :)

Comment: @Jun-Dai Bates-Kobashigawa as far as I know smoothly specified versions works good only for transitive dependencies (to resolve conflicts), but sbt is mostly direct and only one dependency from `sbt-launcher` perspective.

Comment: @dk14 for a project that's very true, but if I'm writing a simple script/utility to share, forcing a download of an older version of sbt to run it seems pretty dumb—I would never do that in Ruby.

Comment: @Jun-DaiBates-Kobashigawa for a simple script (with rich DSL requirements) - you could avoid sbt at all and use direct (let's say some native/external file-io lib) operations. Dependency resolution (for libraries you use) could be handled with [ammonite scripting](https://github.com/lihaoyi/Ammonite), the downside is that you'll be possibly bound to some ammonite version, but the upside is that you might not need to update it at all, but rely completely on ivy-dependencies. Basically it's like bash (in which you usually don't care about version) with easy dependency management.